# How to get Current Item ID in search scope

Tags: sxa, content-search

In Page I used search result to display items from Template, and this template contains "drop link field" I need to filter these results like that
[image] 
I need to use "Current Item ID" in search scope to filter results, IS There a way to get Context Item in scope???

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to do? What have you tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible out of the box. But you can add such functionality (extend the SXA) pretty easily by adding your own "search token" (adding a processor to one of SXA pipelines).

SXA can enrich search queries with Search Query Tokens. Take a look at exiting processors in `resolveSearchQueryTokens` pipeline. What you want to achieve is almost the copy of the existing token - `CurrentTemplate` (it is located here `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Pipelines.ResolveSearchQueryTokens`).

There are some blog posts which can help you with, for example, this one: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html.